Connector type and pinout for this surplus flight cap headset?
I picked up a flight cap that is similar to this one. In my search, it seems to be frequently described as a soviet Mig flight cap. No idea when/where it was manufactured, but it looks like it could be fun and goofy to hook comms to while the flight sim sounds go to the regular speakers.

The connector looks like the following:

With the pins numbered from 1-5 clockwise from the notch.
In basic testing, it would appear that pins 1 and 2 are used for a mono signal to both headphones. Pins 4 and 5 appear to be for the microphone but when checking signals with Audacity, the microphone barely transmits anything besides spots of noise when I tap it.
These questions are in the context of a flight simulator usage:

What type connector is this? It's too large for a XS12 or GX12 connector, my GX16 connector hasn't come in yet to check.

Does anyone know how to connect it? Is pin 3 for PTT and, if so, how should it be wired up?



Thank you for your response! I don't think a DIN would work because of the pin placement (they are spread out more than DIN pins are). My GX16 connector came in and it mates, but is loose and the headset connector doesn't have the threads for the gx16 to lock in.
I'll look into building the FET pre-amp, but am still curious what pin 3 could be used for?

I don't have an oscilloscope to measure output voltage but a direct resistance measurement across the mic leads shows ~146ohms with my multimeter. So I'm expecting it's not high impedance. I guess I should check my audacity settings.
The 3rd pin being ground lines up with llama3:8b's explanation, and that LLM says that many times the 3rd pin is left disconnected. So I guess I'll just have to give it a test =)
